# Web components: inheriting from DOM prototypes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component

One part of the currently developed Web Components specification is that one will be able to create one's own HTML element, e.g. by calling the new `document.register`. An example is given here: https://github.com/mozilla/web-components/blob/master/demo/demo.html

As one can see, a new `x-bar` element is created by having its prototype being inherited from the prototype of an HTML span element.

Now I tried the following in Firefox Nightly (with `document.register` support, by the way):

```
var x = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);
```

I have been thinking that this would be the first step in extending/customizing the behaviour or look of an ordinary `input` element.

However, when I run something like `x.value`, the browser's Javascript engine throws a `TypeError: Value does not implement interface HTMLInputElement`.

Now I am a bit stuck. Is it a limitation of the current implementation or the specification?

Comment: Both answers below were very helpful for my understanding of how custom elements can extend existing element types and how this behaviour can be polyfilled.
As I can only accept one answer, I had to make a choice. I accepted csuwldcat's answer because he gave me the hint that Firefox's pre-release version is actually broken (and its strange behaviour is to what my original question basically boils down).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are having this trouble Marc, is because when you inherit from an *existing native element* to create a new custom element, you need to use the `extends` property of the `document.register(TAG_NAME, OPTIONS)` options object to pass in the desired tag name you would like to inherit from.

To use your new native-inheriting custom element, you'll need to use the `is=""` syntax when writing out your element declaratively in markup - though with JS, it's just like creating any other element - example below. Here are the two polyfills, give them a try and let me know how it works out: Mozilla - https://github.com/mozilla/web-components/blob/master/src/document.register.js - Google: https://github.com/toolkitchen/CustomElements

**Definition & Registration**

```
document.register('x-input', {
  extends: 'input',
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype, { ... })
});
```

**Usage in HTML**

```
<input is="x-input" />
```

**Usage via JavaScript/DOM**

```
document.createElement('x-input')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am currently trying it out. Your code works with your polyfill with the current stable version of Firefox. The trunk version of Firefox, however, which brings its own document.register, still does not work. (I guess the polyfill does nothing in this case as document.register is already there.)

Comment: Your example does also work in Chrome 28 with document.webkitRegister and without any polyfill, which looks like an improper implementation in the latest Firefox.

Comment: @Marc yup, the early implementation of document.register() available in pre-release versions of Firefox is quite stale and does not work correctly - but will be updated soon (now that we're finalizing the spec). When you turn on the pref for Web Components in Firefox pre-release builds it adds that old version, which X-Tags tries to use (as a polyfill should), and appears busted as a result. However, if you disable it, our document.register() polyfill and X-Tag work fine in Firefox.

Comment: Speaking of finalizing the spec, Daniel, the current version https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html does not seem to mention the "extends" property of the element registration options... or am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: The 'extends' option is something we (Google and Mozilla folks collaborating on Web Components) thought to include ahead of it existing in the custom element spec. Without this, it becomes very difficult to polyfill creation of custom elements that inherit from existing native elements.

Comment: @Marc We have modified the polyfill to account for the issue you identified (the spec had been modified and we hadn't accounted for a piece of the change) - perhaps you can update or delete the above bug-report-ish comment now that it is outdated?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the particulars of the x-tags polyfill for `document.register()`, but what this looks like with a native implementation is something like this:

```
<script>
  var XFooProto = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);

  // Define its JS API.
  XFooProto.showVal = function() {
    alert(this.value);
  };

  var XFoo = document.webkitRegister('x-foo', {prototype: XFooProto});

  var xfoo = document.createElement('input', 'x-foo');
  xfoo.value = 50;

  xfoo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.showVal();
  });

  document.body.appendChild(xfoo);   
</script>
```

This [example](http://jsbin.com/eyojob/2/) works in Chrome Canary 28. You currently need the "Enable experimental WebKit features" flag flipped on in `about:flags` to get `document.webkitRegister()`.

I suspect if you do something similar with the FF polyfill, things may work out. You can also check out the polyfills at https://github.com/toolkitchen if you're interested in creating custom elements with `<element>` and/or using the other web component specs.

Comment: Note that my question has nothing to do with the x-tags polyfill itself; I just used their demo code for motivation.

Comment: I tried your example, and it doesn't work in Firefox Trunk because xfoo becomes simply an ordinary input element. In fact, in your code you are creating xfoo with a call to createElement that receives 'input' as its first argument. Isn't the second argument 'x-foo' simply ignored because createElement is only defined for one element?

Comment: Okay, got your example working in Chrome 28, which is obviously respecting the second argument to document.createElement. By the way, is this somewhere documented?

Comment: Please forget my last question; found the extension to createElement in the Custom Elements draft.